# How to get the id of current saved model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On the store() method of a model, I want to save two more models. I need the id of the current model that I am storing. How can I get that?

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request, Property $property)
{
    /*******************************************************
     * Validation sent data
     * Validate e forme ersali user
     *******************************************************/

    $data = $request->validate([
        'type' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'base_capacity' => 'required',
        'max_occupancy' => 'required',
    ]);

    Property::create($data);

    PropertyDetail::create([
        'property_id' => 1,
        'state' => $request->state,
        'city' => $request->city,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'post_code' => $request->post_code,
        'placearea' => $request->place_area,
        'telephone' => $request->telephone,
    ]);
}
```

Here I hard-coded the property id in the property detail. However, I want to get the id of the current property I just created above that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ok-ish approach

1. Create an instance of `Property`

```php
$property = Property::create($data);
```

2. Reference it

```
PropertyDetail::create([
        'property_id' => $property->id, // here it is
        'state' =>$request->state,
        'city' =>$request->city,
        'address' =>$request->address,
        'post_code' =>$request->post_code,
        'placearea' =>$request->place_area,
        'telephone' =>$request->telephone,
    ]);
```

### Safer approach

Safer approach is nearly identical, except you're using two queries and queries can fail. You want to make sure that either both succeed or none succeeds. For that, we use transactions.

What we're making safe about is ensuring data got to the database.

```php
public function store(Request $request,Property $property)
{
    /*******************************************************
     * Validation sent data
     * Validate e forme ersali user
     *******************************************************/

    $data = $request->validate([
        'type' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'base_capacity' => 'required',
        'max_occupancy' => 'required',
    ]);

    \DB::transaction(function() use ($data, $request) {
        $property = Property::create($data);

        PropertyDetail::create([
            'property_id' => $property->id,
            'state' =>$request->state,
            'city' =>$request->city,
            'address' =>$request->address,
            'post_code' =>$request->post_code,
            'placearea' =>$request->place_area,
            'telephone' =>$request->telephone,
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Use transactions is recommended :)

Comment: ok but when i use transaction the $requests become undefied variable . thanks for the good answer btw

Comment: This is due to function scope, pass $request to inner function `\DB::transaction(function() use ($data, $request) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can get `id` from `Property` using the model returned by `create` method and the use it where you need.

```
$property = Property::create($data);
PropertyDetail::create([
        'property_id' => $property->id,
        'state' =>$request->state,
        'city' =>$request->city,
        'address' =>$request->address,
        'post_code' =>$request->post_code,
        'placearea' =>$request->place_area,
        'telephone' =>$request->telephone,
    ]);
```